# Why my graph not plotting predicted values in different and my there are two markings in x and y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am encountering an issue with my Matplotlib graph where I'm seeing unexpected markings on the x and y axes. I've attached an image of the graph for reference. I'm unsure why this is happening and how to resolve it.

I'm using the following code to create the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming df1 and other necessary variables are defined

plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
fontsize = 15
plt.title("Nonlinear Extrapolation of Revenues - Actual vs. Forecast", fontsize=fontsize)
ax = plt.axes()

# Setting the limits before plotting the data
plt.xlim(0, 18)
plt.ylim(-500, 3000)

Actual = np.array(df1.Actual1)
Forecast = np.array(df1['Forecast Fit'])

# Plotting the lines with different colors
plt.plot(Forecast, marker='o', color="green", label="Forecast")
plt.plot(Actual, marker='o', color="blue", label="Actual")

plt.legend(loc="center right")
plt.show()
```

The graph is intended to display the comparison between actual and forecasted revenues. However, the x and y axes are showing additional markings, which I did not expect. I suspect there may be an issue with the data or how I'm setting the axis limits. Can anyone help me identify the problem and suggest a solution?

Comment: You need to remove `ax = plt.axes()` because that creates an extra plot on top of the already started one (it was created when you called `plt.tittle()`).  See also [matplotlib's object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/)

Comment: If you don't see the green curve, probably it is exactly the same as the blue curve, which is plotted last.  If this is a predicted curve, it is a case of severe overfitting.